# Google app engine:BigTable Client like toad for oracle

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, bigtable

BigTable Client like toad for oracle or SQL Server Management Studio Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replicate an App Engine instance to MySQL using AppRocket:
  http://wiki.github.com/k7d/approcket/how-does-it-work

Another option that might suffice is the ability to change the datastore backend to SQLLite (for dev_appserver only ... not your production instances), then use one of the [SQLLite Client GUIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507506/what-are-good-open-source-gui-sqlite-database-managers)